# Get the requesting app name in WCF data service

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any reliable way to find from which Application the Request to a WCF Service originates? I know I can find the user name, domain, IP, etc. from the HTTP context, but what about the App name? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications don't have names, in general, so no.

If you mean the name of the executable, then, no, it's none of the server's business, really.